# Starting camunda bpm OSGI bundle

Tags: startup, osgi-bundle, camunda

I'm trying to add camunda bpm osgi bundle [1] https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform-osgi to a java project , however not clear on the following statement.

"Before you start you have to install all the required bundles into your OSGi runtime. "

So does it mean we need to add all the dependency jars to a dropins folder?

When i just add camunda-bpm-osgi jar to dropins ,following error is given.
 Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.camunda.bpm.engine; version="[7.5.0,7.6.0)"

But the latest GA release of camunda that i can find is 7.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the master branch which already implements against the latest camunda alpha. Try the last stable branch: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform-osgi/tree/1.3  and camunda version will be 7.4.0.